# Markdown seems not to work in tag information excerpts

Tags: bug, status-completed, markdown, tag-wiki

Today I noticed that when you click on a tag, it displays the "tag wiki" information at the top of the page.  However, it appears that Markdown processor wasn't applied to it.

The bug appears in [[linux]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/linux) SO tag and even in [[bug]](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bug) meta tag.

(And I suppose if it was applied, it wouldn't solve the problem with links of style `[xxx][1]`, since the `[1]: xxx.com` part would have been trimmed away).

Comment: excerpts are looking good now, but if you uncomfortable with status-completed I'd can flick this to status-declined

Comment: @waffles, thanks, the fix looks much better.  Further improvement falls under [feature-request] and requires a separate proposal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I added some better html stripping algorithms that make [linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/linux) look good, and [Haskell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/haskell) look good.

The stripping of markdown is by-design. I did not want to allow too much noise there cause its prime screen real estate.

For example, if we allowed markdown we would allow:

t
h
i
s

b
a
d

e
x
c
e
r
p
t

And...

*t* h *i* s **b** a  **d** <sup>excerpt</sup>

Instead we attempt to strip all formatting for the excerpt.

An additional issue is that we use the excerpt for the tag hover, we really do not want to allow any formatting there it would distract users (even more)

Comment: Well, the markdown markup itself is more noisy. :)

Comment: Noise?  Do you really treat _line breaks_ as unnecessary noise?

Comment: Maybe that should be "inappropriate formatting for a more restricted vertical space" rather than "noise".

Comment: I think we can limit to use some simple (and most important) markups such as bold, italic and linking. Without them I feel irritated.

Comment: ook, i got the point. Then all the formatting should be stripped before the text is saved. For example, it looks very dirt when their is as asterisk around a word because someone intended it to be italic.

Answer (score 3):

For illustration this is the [`haskell` tag page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/haskell)
[image: Screen shot of haskell tag page]

Comment: That "lambda" was really lucky to survive!

Comment: yeah that image should not be there ...