# Tag box on top of Questions page doesn't show markdown backticks

Tags: support, bug, status-bydesign, tag-wiki, tags

If you make a Tag Wiki entry, you can use the markdown backticks to show something is a tag (as is done quite often on these sites) and it shows it on the Tag info page.  If you then go to the Tag Questions page, it just shows normal backticks.

**Tag Info Page:**

[image: Tag Info Page]

**Tag Questions Page:**

[image: Tag Questions Page]

Here is a screenshot (**Tag Info Page**) showing that brackets are stripped out also:

[image]

**EDIT:**  It would also be great if the [new tag posting feature](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66965/is-there-some-markup-to-post-tags/69482#69482) would work for tag wikis.  Then it could look like so:

The [excel](/questions/tagged/excel) tag is used for referencing the Excel spreadsheet application from Microsoft.  If your question is about VBA then also tag it [vba](/questions/tagged/vba).  If it is about an Excel formula or worksheet function, then tag it [worksheet-function](/questions/tagged/worksheet-function).

Comment: Duplicate: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/62208/markdown-seems-not-to-work-in-tag-information-excerpts

Comment: @Georg, This may be a subset of that, but I think this specific case can stand on its own.

Comment: Ah, you meant it to be specifically about the back-ticks? Didn't read that way to me.

Comment: @George, good point, I misnamed them, I'll fix that.

Comment: back-ticks are for code, not emphasis...

Comment: @Shog9, I don't use them for emphasis, I use them to show something is a tag, as has been done standardly by many on Meta.

Comment: Uh, @Lance, your first sentence talks about using them for emphasis...

Comment: @Shog9, you got me there.  I'll edit it.

Comment: Do you not like using the square brackets as suggested?

Comment: @random, I used the square brackets also, see the current state where the square brackets don't work, link in 2nd comment to waffles answer.

Comment: It works in the body of the wiki, since the wiki post type is pretty much the same as a question or answer. See [an example here](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/tags/terminology/info). Probably won't work in the excerpt, though, but as Peter notes below this is by design.

Comment: @Grace, yes, I'm asking them to change the design so that the excerpt will have some way of showing tags.

Answer (score 3):

This is pretty much a duplicate **[of this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63656/allow-back-quote-code-formatting-syntax-in-tag-wiki-excerpt)**. I answered that one, but it doesn't have a bounty... so:

**[No markdown in the excerpt is by design](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/62208/markdown-seems-not-to-work-in-tag-information-excerpts/62218#62218)** in order to keep confusing visual cues at a minimum in an area of prime screen real estate.

The idea is that tag excerpts are at the top of the screen in an area where you expect post summaries to be, so any sort of visual formatting on the excerpts will distract the eye from the focus of the page (the post summaries). This would include back-ground color formatting for tags in an excerpt. The reason for the formatting doesn't really change how distracting it is.

Finally, there is now a **[specific box for the tag wiki excerpt](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/62732/markup-between-excerpt-tags-is-not-stripped/62733#62733)**. So it's quite simple to not put markdown in the excerpt.

Answer (score 2):

This is by design, we are not allowing any html through for the tag wiki excerpts.

We would like to keep that section clean and simple, we want to take the minimal amount of focus away from the questions in the list.

Comment: @waffles, couldn't you allow the backticks only, so that we can use them to refer to tags, as we do on Meta all the time.

Comment: @waffles, could you please allow brackets at least, something to that I can use to denote a tag.  See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/excel/info).  Please allow a little flexibility.

Comment: @Lance, I will have a chat with Jeff about this, we may be able to push some minimal amount of formatting through

Comment: Needing to use the tag in the excerpt is akin to the definitions that use the same word to define itself. @lan

Comment: I have to say that the Excel tag explanation is very unhelpful if you don't already know what Excel is. The tag explanation states how to use the tag, but it doesn't explain what Excel is. ------ [PHP has a decent tag explanation](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/php/info).... as an example of how it can be done.

Comment: @random, if you look at the link in my example, you'll see where I reference other tags so that people will tag combinations right.

Comment: @Peter, I don't think tag info text needs to fully explain what something is, I think some knowledge of the subject is ok to assume.  I'm explaining how to use the `Excel` tag, so that it's used correctly.

Comment: @waffles, I just tried double-quotes, but that doesn't work either.

Comment: @waffles, see my edit on using the new tag posting functionality.