# Show a live preview of tag wiki excerpt as well, when editing tag wiki

Tags: feature-request, user-interface, suggested-edits, markdown-preview, tag-wiki-excerpt

It seems that tag excerpts are not displayed verbatim/in full on the Tags pages. That's fine but it makes it very hard to fine tune tag excerpts to display optimally, especially for editors who must go through the suggest > vote > approve process for each tweak.

- [New tags page mangles tag wiki excerpts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82700/new-tags-page-mangles-tag-wiki-excerpts)
- [Why is the Etymology tag excerpt missing some words on the Tags page?](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/245/why-is-the-etymology-tag-excerpt-missing-some-words-on-the-tags-page))

I assume there is a set of rules the excerpt display code goes through to trim the excerpts, and also that this set of rules will be tweaked from time to time as the developers find more heuristics.

So why not reuse this excerpt trimming function to implement a live preview of the tag wiki excerpt as a partner to the live tag wiki preview? This way we can be sure that our tag wiki edits, even if they are mere suggestions, won't be mangled in ways we cannot deterministically predict once they make it through to the Tags page. This is especially important because suggested edit reviewers don't have any direct way to check this either.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/62266/tag-box-on-top-of-questions-page-doesnt-show-markdown-backticks

Comment: I believe that the Tag Markup (in the vein of [Tag:John-Skeet]) show up visible on the preview, but not on the actual page, as well.

Comment: As a workaround, you can use the Regex101 suite I created for [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/344628/295232).