# Is there a proofing tool for writing tag excerpts?

Tags: discussion, tag-wiki-excerpt

One peculiar thing about editing the excerpt for a tag wiki is that sometimes the leading words are omitted in certain contexts. Sometimes this is desirable, but sometimes it comes across as weird. Here are some examples I've run into, with the removed words shown in strike-through.

- <s>C# (pronounced "see sharp") is</s> a high level, statically typed, multi-paradigm programming
- <s>HTML (Hypertext Markup Language) is</s>  the standard markup language
- <s>This tag</s> should be used only on questions that are about Objective-C features
- <s>DO NOT use this tag</s> unless you are addressing Apple's iPhone and/or iPod touch specifically
- <s>Use this tag</s> (along with an appropriate programming-language tag) for programming questions relating to the Apache HTTP

Is there a [proofing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepress_proofing) tool I can use to preview my edits before they take effect? Or at the very least, is there a place that defines all the rules in how excerpts are automatically rewritten? Otherwise I find myself going back to edit the same tag, which is especially annoying if I'm waiting for my edits to pass a review queue.

Comment: You should ask this on [MSO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/) if it pertains mainly to Stack Overflow.

Comment: This affects all sites in the network.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is no official proofing tool. The rules are described in [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/82702/295232), and assuming the regex there is up to date (given your test cases, it is), [this Regex101 suite](https://regex101.com/r/3DK9ny/2/) allows you to check how the excerpt will be shown in the tag autocomplete box when asking/editing a question. Just look at the part which isn't matched:

[image]