# Please let us show a small icon/graphic in the tag excerpt

Tags: feature-request, images, tag-wiki-excerpt

I know that the tag excerpts are [prime real estate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/62208/markdown-seems-not-to-work-in-tag-information-excerpts/62218#62218), but I think it would be nice if we had the option to add a small product icon/graphic to the excerpt.

Here's how it looks now:
[image]

And here's what I was thinking:
[image]

To make the tag wiki excerpts uniform, you could have us upload an image separately (like: "Choose the excerpt image, no larger than 80px"), rather than letting us put the image in the markdown - this way, you don't have to modify the "no markdown in excerpts" rule.

I would also think a size constraint would make sense - in my example above, I used an 80x80 icon (which only adds a single line to the excerpt, not using up much extra space). For cases where there is no icon, you could use a muted version of the site icon as a placeholder (or just a blank, white image).

Comment: I actually like the picture just because it makes the box a bit more interesting. Right now its a big wall of text that immediately people don't want to read.

Comment: @sth Doh! Thanks for the edit...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Generally, I agree. However, I just want to point out something I noticed in the last paragraph:

> For cases where there is no icon, you could use a muted version of the site icon as a placeholder (or just a blank, white image).

I'd prefer if there was no image at all so that it looks how it currently does. Using the site icon or a blank image takes up valuable screen space that is better served by having no icon at all.

Comment: Yeah, that would work fine too - I just assumed that the page template would have a blank spot if there was no image.

Comment: Why are there more upvotes for my post than on the question itself?

Answer (score 1):

I disagree that *users* should be able to do this.

I really like the mockup, but I think this is a far better opportunity for for-profit advertising than for users to add images (aka free advertising).