# Make tag wiki suggested edits' and revision histories' rendering consistent with actual tag wiki excerpt rendering

Tags: bug, status-norepro, tag-wiki-excerpt

I suggested this source for the [kbd](/questions/tagged/kbd) wiki excerpt:

```
questions relating to the <kbd> tag, which can be used in posts to generate "keys".
```

I did this knowing that wiki excerpts have some [HTML and Markdown stripping](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/62208/markdown-seems-not-to-work-in-tag-information-excerpts) applied, so I figured it would just appear as `<kbd>` in the actual wiki excerpt.

The info page looked fine while the edit was pending, but on the suggested edit page, the excerpt appeared as:

```
questions relating to the tag, which can be used in posts to generate "keys".
```

I then second-guessed myself about whether `<kbd>` would get stripped, and changed the pending edit to:

```
questions relating to the &lt;kbd&gt; tag, which can be used in posts to generate "keys".
```

But to my dismay, when the [suggested edit](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/1992) was applied, it appeared literally as I had entered it in that last iteration (with `&lt;kbd&gt;`).

My [follow-up edit suggestion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/2027) to fix the problem with the excerpt was rejected, probably due to the above issue.

Can the rendering for wiki excerpt revisions and suggested edits be changed to match the rendering of the actual excerpts? This would prevent a lot of confusion and fruitless editing.

Comment: I have just stumbled across the problem so this still appears to be an issue. Any progress or suggestions?

Comment: @Chris Not that I know of :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this issue has been corrected; I'm not entirely sure when, but I can't reproduce this issue.